# allocate a matrix of struct in c++ with new

Tags: c++

for a kind of pattern recognition I have defined a very simple struct

```
struct object
{
  int color;
  int shape;
}
```

now I want to allocate a matrix of this struct for all pixel of a picture in c++ (so not with malloc), like I do it for normal fields (matrix) like:

```
struct object_A = allocate(objects, dim_x, dim_y);
```

my first try was:

```
struct object_A MyProgramm::allocate(object object_A, int x, int y)
{

         object var[x][y];   

          return var
}
```

better surely would be something like:

```
struct object_A MyProgramm::allocate(object object_A, int x, int y)
{

    var = new struct object* [x];

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
      var[i] = new struct object[y];

    return var
}
```

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: idea: I see no particular reason not to use `std::vector` or `std::array` or a combination

Comment: btw allocation a matrix of `object`s isnt that different from allocating a matrix of `int`s

Comment: I think you need a C++ book, it's hard to learn a programming language via trial and error. And there are many indications in your code that tell me you're not following a book.

Comment: @mkd This parameter  object object_A is not used in your functions. What does it mean?

Comment: You don't need the `struct` keyword in C++ (only when declaring a `struct)`, nor would you write a free function to allocate some struct, but write a proper class with constructor and destructor.

Comment: Your C++ book should have plenty of examples of doing this. What, specifically, in your C++ book's explanation of how to do this you do not understand?

Comment: Why not `std::vector<std::vector<object> > object_matrix(dim_x, std::vector<object>(dim_y));`?

Answer (score -2):

thks. for the creative comment S.M., Iam sure, you never startet some years ago!

Ok, I solved the problems alone and here is the final programm

```
int myprogram::allocate(object** new_object, int x, int y)
{

 if(new_object == NULL)
{
  object** new_object = new object*[x];

 for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  new_object[i] = new object[y];

    return 1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This leaks everything allocated, and only `new_object[0]` is ever set, no other rows. And never modifies `new_object`